# RVM and Gemfile - not always loading correct ruby, only when 'cd .. & cd myproject'

Tags: bash, rvm, zshrc, iterm2

> **TL;DR:** Every time I open a new [iterm2](/questions/tagged/iterm2) tab, [rvm](/questions/tagged/rvm) goes back to default version, it doesn't use the Gemfile ruby version

My Gemfile has

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
```

and I use rvm 1.25.14.

RVM is smart and reads the ruby version in gemfile, except for this edge case

Doing

```
# NOTE: iterm2 
$ cd myproject
$ ruby -v
> ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
```

but cmd+t, creating a new tab, staying in that directoy,

```
$ pwd
>../myproject
$ ruby -v
> ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```

ruby 1.9.3 is my default, which is fine. What am I missing in my bash (or .zshrc ) ? to make this work?

```
#FILE .zshrc
#...stuff

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

Using cmd+d, splitting the terminal vertically, has the same problem. rvm goes to default, ignoring Gemfile. Thanks for helping guys !

Comment: I've had same issue and I'm using a simple workaround: added `cd .` at the end of `.bashrc` (`.zshrc` in your case) and now it works as it should, but I know it's not a true answer, as it fits my needs I didn't spend more time on it.

Comment: @zrl3dx please make an answer out of it :)

Comment: @zrl3dx this didn't work from me. `cd .` does nothing here. `cd ..` followed by `cd myproject` works...

Comment: That's strange, I'll test it later with zsh.

Comment: i think the clue is [tag:iterm2]. I just tested in [tag:Terminal] on somebody else's computer and the (seemingly) same setup worked.

Comment: rvm hooks cd, so make sure rvm is loaded before changing directories into your Gemfile-containing directory.

Comment: It's also worth noting that macOS doesn't treat login and interactive shells the same way that Linux does. If you've changed your shell or its startup scripts, you may run into problems with RVM not being loaded as a function when you open a new terminal or terminal tab.

Answer (score 0):

This should be shell- and terminal-agnostic (unfortunately I can't test it on iterm2 since I don't have any Mac machine):

Add `cd ${PWD}` to your `.zshrc` and this should force RVM to load current gemset.

Comment: I awarded you the bounty even though it was a hack and it didn't work ;) `pushd` followed by `popd` did what `cd ${PWD}` couldn't do. Please add this to your answer and I'll mark it as 'correct'-ish.

Comment: Didn't solve for me doing it on `.zshrc`, but did solve doing it on `.zlogin`. Guess the important part is for it to be after the sourcing of rvm.

Comment: renatolond, yes that is the right answer.

Comment: Relying on the cd hook is common, but can be problematic in some environments. I've found it to be an 80% solution, but with some non-deterministic failure cases. Also, RVM is *not* shell agnostic. It requires a Bourne-compatible shell, and will not work with shells like Fish.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `cd .` in `.zlogin` after the RVM script.

Answer (score 0):

### Use RVM's Built-In Ability to Reload Configuration Files in the Current Directory

RVM leverages the `cd` command, so while there may be a specific solution for your situation the more general solution is to use direnv, dotenv, or similar to ensure that you're triggering RVM properly when changing directories.

In my personal experience, one of the two placed into your project's .envrc or similar will resolve many issues, and highly recommend [direnv](https://direnv.net/) with or without its standard library's [ruby layout](https://direnv.net/man/direnv-stdlib.1.html#codelayout-rubycode) or [use](https://direnv.net/man/direnv-stdlib.1.html#codeuse-ltprogramnamegt-ltversiongtcode) commands. For example:

1. read in the current directory's .ruby-* or .rvmrc files

   ```
   rvm use .
   ```
2. Reload RVM, which will re-read various dotfiles if the relevant `~/.rvmrc` variables have been exported (see dotfile settings in next section).

   ```
   rvm reload
   ```

The first option is best IMHO, and seems to "just work" on all my Bourne-compatible shells, but the other should work too.

### Some Key `~/.rvmrc` Dotfile Settings

With either of the solutions above, you may need some of the following items set in your global `~/.rvmrc` file:

1. `export rvm_gemset_create_on_use_flag=1`
2. `export rvm_install_on_use_flag=1`
3. `export rvm_project_rvmrc_default=1`

Which ones you really need will somewhat depend on how you expect RVM to behave under any given set of circumstances. However, I've found that using RVM's ability to reload its settings (rather than relying on the `cd` hooks, and calling that functionality directly to be much more reliable. Your mileage may vary.

### See Also

- https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc
- https://rvm.io/workflow/projects

Answer (score -1):

I seems that for a local open terminal [rvm](/questions/tagged/rvm) don't load its scripts. Add the code to the end of [.bashrc](/questions/tagged/.bashrc), it then should:

```
if [ -z "$MY_RUBY_HOME" ]; then
   [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
fi
```

Comment: downvote because of bombastic and false statement. RVM *does* use Gemfile ruby if provided, but I have an edge case where it doesn't work.

Comment: is this working on your end? It already works from me when `cd`-ing into the directory, but not with new tab (no `cd`-ing performed). I don't see what in your answer makes a relevant difference to the [tag:.zshrc] in the question.

Comment: is your default rvm ruby different than the ruby you are using in that project you open a new tab in? FYI, I added to Q that I use [tag:iterm2] with [tag:zsh]

Comment: @oma I have no default rvm specified for the test project, I just removed .ruby- files, and specified ruby version in Gemfile. But anyway, I guess the issue is with `.zshrc`. Try to insert to it an echo line, and then open a new terminal.

Comment: `rvm list` - what's your default? is your gemfile ruby different? It's kinda hard when you can't reproduce the problem. Appreciate the efforts, but 'echo in .zshrc' is too little specific, what should be echo-ed?

Comment: @oma `what should be echo-ed?` anything. Then you open a new tab with `cmd+t,` from the exists one you should see that `echo`. Please reproduce

Comment: echo anything? I already get some output on cmd+t for some other things I have in my .zshrc. Did you miss the "if I cd out and cd back in, rvm loads correctly" in my Q? That's after cmd+t too, obviously.  "Please reproduce"? I can reproduce... what do you mean? It sounds like you can't reproduce and that makes it difficult.

Comment: @oma if loading of your `.zsh` after `cmd+t` is completed well, I guess there shpuld be done some addtonal steps to make sure that rvm is loaded correctly